# jQuery - change class with timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a CSS slider that I'm using with a bit of jQuery to change the class of the list item on click. I would also like to have the slider on a timer so every 5s it auto executes the removeClass of the selected list item and adds "selected" class to the next list item in the list if there is no user interaction.

At the same time as changing the class on the li element it needs to change the #slide_images transform to what it needs to be (0px,1100px,2200px,3300px or 4400px) etc.

If it does have user interaction via them selecting a link for a slide then the timer should stop until page reload.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="slide_container">
<div style="transform: translateX(0px);" id="slide_images">

<div class="slide1">   
<img src="http://example.com/1.jpg">
<div class="slide-content1">
slide1content
</div>
</div>
<div class="slide2">   
<img src="http://example.com/2.jpg">
<div class="slide-content2">
slide1content
</div>
</div>
<div class="slide3">   
<img src="http://example.com/3.jpg">
<div class="slide-content3">
slide1content
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.slide-content1,.slide-content2,.slide-content3,.slide-content4,.slide-content5{position:absolute;top:20px;left:0;padding:110px 0 0;width:1100px;color:#fff}
.slide-content2{left:1100px}
.slide-content3{left:2200px}
.slide-content4{left:3300px}
.slide-content5{left:4400px}
#slide_container{width:1100px;height:580px;overflow:hidden;margin:0 auto}
#slide_images{width:5500px;-webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;transition:all .5s ease-in-out}
#slide_images img{padding:0;margin:0;float:left;border:none}
```

Here is the script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slidenav').on('click', 'li', function(){
    $("#slide_images").css("transform","translateX("+$(this).index() * -1100+"px)");
    $(".slidenav li").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  });
 });

});
```

Thanks for any help :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have  an example with a working rotator. It will rotate every 5 seconds when there is no user interaction. When you click on a item, the timer resets to 0 and continues after 5 seconds with rotation.

```
HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul class="slidenav">
      <li>slide1</li>
      <li>slide2</li>
      <li>slide3</li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
ul.slidenav li {
  color: #000;
}
ul.slidenav li.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var slides = $(".slidenav li");

    //Init slide 1
    slideTo(slides[0]);

    var slideIndex = 0;
    var slideTime = animate();

    $(".slidenav li").click(function() {
      //Reset the interval to 0 and start it again
      clearInterval(slideTime);
      slideTime = animate();


      var selectedIndex = $(this).index();
      var slide = slides[selectedIndex];
      slideTo(slide);

    });

    function slideTo(slide) {
       $(".slidenav li").removeClass("selected");
        $(slide).addClass("selected");
        slideIndex = jQuery(slide).index(); 
    }

    function animate() {
      return setInterval(function() {
                var slide = slides[slideIndex];
                slideTo(slide)
                slideIndex++;
                if (slideIndex == slides.length) {
                  slideIndex = 0; 
                }
            }, 5000);
    }

});
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ah1CTexSjnROAEPMAitk?p=preview

Comment: I'm sorry I gave a useless description. Can you please see my updated description and code. Your answer seems perfect to me I just need to adapt it to fit what I need. Thank you!

Comment: You can apply your code to the example I gave. It's not the meaning that I am making your homework but helping you to find the right way.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try although it seems to be using jQuery to slide rather than the css transform as I wanted. I will try to find a way through it, cheers.

Comment: Well I've tried for nearly 5 hours now and got nowhere. I just don't understand Javascript well enough to make this work. I am just going to have to leave it as user interaction only as I've run out of time. I've marked your answer correct though as it is obviously right I just can't make it work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To execute something with a delay, you can use `setTimeout()`.
You can use a `delayTime` variable and then modify it on user click event.
A quick approach to the solution would be

```
var delayTime = 5000; // milliseconds
$(function() {
  $('.slidenav').click(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('.slidenav li').removeClass('newClass');
    }, delayTime);
  });
  $('.clickedLink').click(function () {
    delayTime = 0;
  });
});
```

Notice, I also shortened the code a little bit: `$(ready)` and `.on('click')`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this codesnippet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".slider li:first-child").addClass("active");
        setTimeout(autoAddClass, 1000);
});

function autoAddClass(){
    var next = $(".active").removeClass("active").next();
    if(next.length)
        $(next).addClass('active');
    else
        $('.slider li:first-child').addClass('active');
    setTimeout(autoAddClass, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start by [setting an interval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), and once your user does his interaction, you can clear that interval using [clearInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp). Here is a pseudo code:

```
var interval = setInteval(function(){
  // do whatever here...
}, 5000);

$('yourSelector').click(function(){
  clearInterval(interval);
  // do whatever....
});
```